# A function to display the result of rpart in party language in R language

Tags: r, function, rpart, party

I'd like to create a function to display the result of `rpart` with `partykit`.
I converted the result of `rpart` with `as.party` with the following code and displayed the tree structure.

```
library(partykit)
library(rpart)

result1 <- rpart(Species~.,data = iris)
plot(as.party(result1))
```

So, I defined rpart and as.party in the function and executed it.

```
rpart_party <- function(formula, data){
  result1 <- rpart(formula = formula ,data = data)
  return(as.party(result1))
}
plot(rpart_party(Species~., data = iris))
```

However, the following error occurred.

> ```
> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
>   invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
> ```

Please tell me how to create a function that transforms the result of `rpart` with `as.party` and displays the structure of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your evaluation of the formula in something like `substitute(...)` to prevent the model call being set to "formula" instead of "Species~." etc.

```
rpart_party <- function(formula, data){
  result1 <- rpart(formula = substitute(formula), data = data)
  return(as.party(result1))
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `rpart(formula = formula, data = data, model = TRUE)` can be used. This stores the `model.frame` in `result1` so that `as.party()` does not have to re-evaluate this and try to look in the right environment...